# mongoid model has two relations with another model - rails mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a User model, and an Order model.  There are two types of users: a seller, and a driver. Both sellers and drivers have many orders, and every order belongs to one seller and one driver. Thus, I want to be able to query for `user.orders` and have it return a particular user's  orders, but also to successfully query for `order.seller` and `order.driver`. How can I establish these relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with.. Pretty sure it works as intended.

`Class User 
  has_many :sales, class_name: 'Order', inverse_of: :seller
  has_many :pickups, class_name: 'Order', inverse_of: :driver
end`

`Class Order
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :sale
  belongs_to :driver, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :pickup
end`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no clear way to have 2 relations share a field on another model. You could always do something like this if you have a field that differentiates drivers and sellers if they are a mix tho it won't work.

**User.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
```

**Order.rd**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
def seller
  users.where(job: User.DRIVER)
end
```

### UPDATE

**User.rb**

```
has_many :sales, class_name: 'Order', inverse_of: :seller
has_many :pickups, class_name: 'Order', inverse_of: :driver
def orders
  Order.or(seller_id: self.id, driver_id: self.id)
end
```

**Order.rb**

```
belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'Order', inverse_of: :sales
belongs_to :driver, class_name: 'Order', inverse_of: :pickups
```

Comment: See my answer. I think it's an elegant solution but I haven't tested it 100%

Comment: Yea that should work and to get `user.orders` you can make a wrapper method that squashes both results.